# I can not do repo init for android_manifest.git

Tags: 16.04, repository, git, android-sdk

I am working with khadas VIM3 development board and I am trying to sync the android pie SDK but it is not working. I am getting syntax error while I do repo init.

I posted this question on the Khadas forum but they said that this is a problem of ubuntu. So, I am putting an error here.

**Error:**

```
Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle
Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
remote: Counting objects: 1, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (30/30)
remote: Total 30 (delta 2), reused 30 (delta 2)
Unpacking objects: 100% (30/30), done.
From https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
   7f7acfe..5e2f32f  main       -> origin/main
   4b32581..352c93b  stable     -> origin/stable
 * [new tag]         v2.10      -> v2.10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/parth/BSP_Storage/vim3_khadas/.repo/repo/main.py", line 56, in <module>
    from subcmds.version import Version
  File "/media/parth/BSP_Storage/vim3_khadas/.repo/repo/subcmds/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    ['%s' % name])
  File "/media/parth/BSP_Storage/vim3_khadas/.repo/repo/subcmds/upload.py", line 27, in <module>
    from hooks import RepoHook
  File "/media/parth/BSP_Storage/vim3_khadas/.repo/repo/hooks.py", line 472
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
**SyntaxError: invalid syntax**
```

Comment: just enforce python3 as the following  $python3 /media/parth/BSP_Storage/vim3_khadas/.repo/repo init ...........